# How can I detect when an element is at a certain part of the screen JavaScript

Tags: javascript

- Do you remember that console video game "Guitar Hero"? Or if you are a little younger, "Piano Tiles"?
- If you don't know what I'm talking about, click on this link to get an idea = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWLKlEg0VMs&ab_channel=MattSterner
- Well, that is exactly what I am doing with this website (on a more basic level of course).

THERE IS NO NEED TO READ THE WHOLE CODE...

- What I need your help with:

Look into the JavaScript code and go to the `animateFunction()` function.
In the `if statement` you will see I wrote a condition that in human language would be "If I press 'Q key' and the square on the left is where it should be when you get the note right, then `console.log(currentNotePosition.bottom);`" and that `if statement` is the same for the notes on the middle line and on the right side.

- The issue:
  When I click on the keys ('Q', 'W', and 'E'), the `console.log(currentNotePosition.bottom)` does execute, but it does it sometimes and not when the note is on the spot it should be when I want it to console.log the bottom position. So basically, my code can't detect when a note is at the place where you can score a point.
- My theory of the issue:
  My code is not able to identify which div/musical_note exactly I want to "score on".

Here is a better place to see and play with my code (tap on the "create" button to start the "game"): https://codepen.io/xavi-font/pen/xxOedzK
(If on the Codepen playground you don't see the "web browser screen" then just pull it up from the bottom, it is a window just like the ones that "contain" the code).

PD: This is written in Vanilla JavaScrpt (No libraries or frameworks).

```js
let speed = 1;

idArray = [];

let topPositionThatAdds = 0;

let squareLeft = {
    color: "red",
    positionLeft: "250px",
    class: 'squareLeft',
}

let squareMiddle = {
    color: "green",
    positionLeft: "750px",
    class: 'squareMiddle',
}

let squareRight = {
    color: "yellow",
    positionLeft: "1250px",
    class: 'squareRight',
}
idList = 0;
randomSquare = [squareLeft, squareMiddle, squareRight];

function generateSquares() {
    let randomValue = randomSquare[Math.floor(randomSquare.length * Math.random())];
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.classList.add(randomValue.class);
    newDiv.style.top = "-100px";

    newDiv.setAttribute("id", idList.toString());
    idList++;
    idArray.push(idList);

    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

    for (let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
        let element = document.getElementById(i.toString());
        animateFunction(element);
    }
}

function animateFunction(element) {
    if (element.style.top == "-100px") {
        const interval = setInterval(function() {
            element.style.top = eval(parseInt(element.style.top) + 1).toString() + "px";
            let currentNotePosition = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 81 /*Q*/ && currentNotePosition.bottom > 700 && currentNotePosition.bottom < 900 && element.classList.contains('squareLeft')) {
                         console.log(currentNotePosition.bottom);
                    }else if (e.keyCode == 87 /*W*/ && currentNotePosition.bottom > 700 && currentNotePosition.bottom < 900 && element.classList.contains('squareMiddle')) {
                         console.log(currentNotePosition.bottom);
                    }else if (e.keyCode == 69 /*E*/ && currentNotePosition.bottom > 700 && currentNotePosition.bottom < 900 && element.classList.contains('squareRight')) {
                        console.log(currentNotePosition.bottom);
                            }
                }
        }, speed);
    }
}

function startGame() {
    let randomGenerationNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 - 250)) + 250;
    const interval = setInterval(generateSquares, randomGenerationNumber);
}
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", startGame);
```

```css
body{
background: yellow;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-size: cover;
}

#bar{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    /* top: 770px; */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(52,162,162);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(52,162,162,.25) 0%, rgba(144,28,103,1) 100%);
    z-index: 2;
}

.squareRight{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 250px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: red;
}

.squareMiddle{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 750px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: green;
}

.squareLeft{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 1250px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TapTap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  
<button id="button">create</button>

<div id="bar"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much for your time, I hope you can help me with this since its been days and I still can't figure it out.

Comment: One of the issues you've got is that there can only ever be one `document.body.onkeyup` handler for the entire document. `document.body.addEventListener` seems like what you were after, as you can assign unlimited listeners, but do that in your codePen and watch the whole thing slow to a crawl even without interaction. Then I'm afraid there's the whole business of setting intervals inside loops inside intervals. Your core approach to this issue (checking distance from the bottom) is generally sound, but the implementation as it stands is just not going to work.

Comment: There are a number of problems with this code. Nested intervals are just one issue. Then there is the part about rewriting the exact same handler code `interval1 * interval2` times for no reason. But most directly, the issue is due to the race condition you've created inside your `animate()` function.

Comment: Check my approach to your problem, I rely upon CSS animation instead javascript, and only have one `key` event to handle the keys - https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/abZxyRj?editors=0011 - it's not perfect but you might find interesting as it has the same functionality but using way less memory